# Cloud Kafka with spring boot gives me errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

Hey I followed a step by step guide for setting up kafka in spring boot.

But now I cannot start the app. Any suggestions :)

error from the log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'functionInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found more then one function in BeanFactory: [persistentEntities, resourceMappings]. Consider providing 'spring.cloud.function.definition' property.
```

What is spring.cloud.function.definition? And how to set it up?
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found more then one function in BeanFactory: [persistentEntities, resourceMappings]. Consider providing 'spring.cloud.function.definition' property.

Comment: You need to show your code and config. The property tells the framework which function to bind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Cloud Function does the following within an application:

1. Searches for ANY Spring managed `bean` that implements OR conforms with the contract of the functional interfaces `Supplier<T>`, `Consumer<T>` and `Function<T, R>`.
2. Mark these `beans` as potential `beans` to be bound to event endpoints (bindings).
3. If there is only one Spring managed `bean` resolved in step 1, then that bean will be the only `bean` bound as the *function* exposed (bound to external event endpoint) by the application - effectively assuming that the application is a [Serverless Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_as_a_service).
4. If there are more than a single Spring managed `bean` resolved in step 1, then Spring Cloud Function will look at the property `spring.cloud.function.definition` to resolved which of those `beans` should be bound to endpoints.
5. If this property is not assigned, then Spring Cloud Function will throw a `IllegalArgumentException` (the one you are getting) complaining that it cannot resolve which beans (of all the potential  *functional* `bean` that it has found) you want exposed.
6. The value assigned to the property `spring.cloud.function.definition` will be read as a [semi-colon separated list of *functional* `bean` names](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream.adoc#multiple-functions-in-a-single-application)

So, to solve your problem, you need to either:

- Just register in the Spring context bean `persistentEntities` or bean `resourceMappings`; but not both.
- Add the following entry to the properties of your Spring context:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=persistentEntities;resourceMappings
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this semicolon thing is quite important, thx!